# Do A and A^-­1 have the same condition number?

Tags: matrix, conditional-statements

I couldn't find any answer how to explain whether A matrice and its singular matrice have the same condition number or not.

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions about programming.

Comment: Yes. The condition number is ||A||*||inv(A)||. Applying this to inv(A) you get ||inv(A)||*||inv(inv(A))|| = ||inv(A)|| * ||A|| = ||A||*||inv(A)||. (Here || . || denotes the norm)